# Efficient search for data in multiple hierarchical data structures in C++

Tags: c++, stdmap, fsm

Hello everyone I have a problem of searching for data inside a big map that I created. I am creating an FSM with my framework. I have several `condition`s that should be appended to certain `Transition`s (based on the following conditions). A `condition` should be appended to a `Transition` between two states s1 & s2, if `state s1` is found in a certain `set s1Set` and `state s2` is found in `set s2Set`.

Since I have several conditions each with it's pair of sets, I created this map to be able to check.

```
std::map<std::set<int>, std::pair<std::set<StateArch*>, std::set<StateArch*> > > mapBypassConditions;
```

The set of ints is my condition and the pair of sets are where I search for S1 and S2.

However, I feel this is very inefficient because for each transition in my FSM I have to go through the entire map and search for S1 and S2 and check if I need to append the condition to it.

Do you guys have any better ideas? Perhaps better organization of the map?

p.s. I am using C++98 as the framework is a bit old and not yet working with newer versions

Comment: Use a [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (`std::unordered_map`) instead of a normal C++ `std::map`.  I know you're using C++98, but you have to get one and use it. You either use boost for that, or find some other implementation. Hashmaps have constant access time if the number of buckets is very high.

Comment: "go through the entire map" Even `std::map` is sorted, and therefore is a binary search on the key. But since your key doesn't seem trivial to compare, you may consider using a hashmap, which I think Boost has a C++98 version

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. Could you guys briefly explain how I can use Hashmap in my case? Should the key be the pair of Sets or the condition?? Like I said I am searching for the states in the set